# How to find the Antisymmetric Closure of a set?

Tags: relations

This is an example exercise from my Algebra class:

> Find the antisymmetric closure of 
>   $$R=\{(1,2),(1,3),(2,2),(2,1)\}$$
>   on 
>   $$\{1,2,3\}$$

I don't see it explicitly defined in the lecture notes and I couldn't find much information about *Antisymmetric Closure* online.

I sort of understand Reflexive, Symmetric and Transitive Closure, but not *Antisymmetric Closure*. How is it defined and how can I find it?

Comment: Symmetry, transitivity and reflexivity are all about pairs that _should_ exist, and therefore the relevant closures are about adding those pairs. Antisymmetry is about pairs that _shouldn't_ exist, and I don't know a canonical way to make that happen.

Comment: To be honest, seeing how I can't find anything good that mentions it, I see a possibility that my professor might have mistypped something...